# remove is not working JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove an `<a> </a>`  element via the ID, which is stored in a variable, like this:

```
function deleteme(counter) {

        alert("Möchten sie wirklick das blau markierte Kreuz löschen?");
         $('<a id=' + counter + '> </a>').remove(); 
    }
```

This is the HTML, which I try to remove

```
    <a id="1">
    <p>ID von 1 XPosition 240, YPosition 53<img src="any.jpg" onclick="deleteme(1)"</p>
    </a>
```

I did make an `alert(counter)` to check if it has the right ID. It has.

How can i fix this up?

Comment: Simply use `$('#' + counter).remove();`

Comment: ah easy as this :/ thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a new element in `$('<a id=' + counter + '> </a>')`.

To select and remove the existing one, do

```
$('#' + counter).remove();
```

Comment: thanks, it works... Thougt I can select the element the same way i created it :/+

Answer (score 0):

Just use only Id selector

```
function deleteme(counter) {    
            alert("Möchten sie wirklick das blau markierte Kreuz löschen?");
             $('#'+ counter).remove(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing the selector in `$()`

Use it like this:

```
$('#' + counter)
```

Always use css-selectos in $, html-tags won't work.

In case you don't know anything about CSS-Selectors, I suggest an introduction to css, like on codeacademy.

Also, I'm pretty sure IDs can't start with a number - consider renaming it to "p1" or "paragraph1" or something like this.

Generally, I would strongly recommend http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/jquery this link.

Comment: id="1" will only work in html5 thanks for pointing it out. Already figuring it out, how I can rename it without crushing my logic

Comment: You could still use `'#paragrah' + counter` in your code.

Comment: the create paragraph process is a bit more complicated than that, hence it is a big application. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Inline html attribute event handlers can only call global functions. Your deleteme function is not global because it is defined inside your document ready handler, so your onclick="deleteme()" can't find it. You need to either move the function outside the ready handler (making it global), or, better, bind the click with jQuery

```
$("#id").click(function () {
    $('#' + counter).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this way make the function can be called in more than one element that u want to delete

**HTML**

```
<a id="1">
   <p>ID von 1 XPosition 240, YPosition 53<img src="any.jpg" onclick="javascript:deleteme($(this))"/></p>
</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
function deleteme(counter) {
    alert("Möchten sie wirklick das blau markierte Kreuz löschen?");
    counter.parent('a').remove(); 
}
```